# c++ include directory "file not found"

Tags: c++, header, include

I'm working on getting an example run for the audioCaffe framework http://multimedia-commons.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?prefix=tools/audioCaffe/

The root directory of this project contains an `include` directory.

Except, when I navigate to `tools` and compile `g++ caffe.cpp` it throws an error:

`caffe.cpp:8:10: fatal error: 'caffe/caffe.hpp' file not found`

note that `include/caffe/caffe.hpp` exists

Comment: Is the `caffe.cpp` inside the `include` directory?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more about the folder structure and from what directory you execute `g++` or I just gotta download the 230MB file to check it out?

Comment: @Nacho it would be easiest if you just downloaded, thanks

Comment: @DimChtz no, but there are files all over the project that `#include caffe/[header].hpp` so it shouldn't need to be, right?

Comment: `caffe.cpp:8:10: fatal error: 'caffe/caffe.hpp' file not found` `include/caffe/caffe.hpp` from these two I think `caffe.cpp` needs to be inside `include` directory so it can reach `caffe/caffe.hpp`

Comment: @DimChtz again, files all over the project reference the header files found in include/caffe/* Even files in that directory. The point of the include directory is that #include "blah" should reference that directory (sorry accidentally deleted)

Comment: Okay, I should download it and check it

Comment: Okay, all you need to do is to tell the compiler where to look for `additional include directories`, the include folder obviously

Comment: If you re using visual studio just go to project properties > C/C++ > additional include directories

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107287/discussion-between-hey-zuse-and-dimchtz).

Comment: @DimChtz that was it `g++ -I/path_to/include file.cpp exec`

Comment: @heyzuse yeah that's it

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned using `g++ caffe.cpp` I assume you execute this command form where `caffe.cpp` file is, which is:

```
audioCaffe/tools/caffe.cpp
```

The `caffe.cpp` file uses `#include "caffe/caffe.hpp"` which is in the include directory:

```
audioCaffe/include/caffe/caffe.hpp
```

So you will need to tell the compiler where to find the headers, you do this with the `-I` option. Compile it with the command:

```
g++ -I ../include caffe.cpp
```